# Git: can I directly look up the tree hash of a tree-ish, such as a path in a specific commit?

Tags: git

Imagine the following repository layout:

```
<repo root>
animals/
  ant/
    ...ant-related files...
  bee/
    ...bee-related files...
  dog/
    ...dog-related files...
```

I'm looking for a command like `git please_show_the_tree_hash_of v2.12:animals/ant`. Does such a command exist; and if yes, what is it?

### What this question is notabout

I've got a workaround, shown below in case it helps anybody. My question is not about a workaround, but about whether a suitable Git command exists.

The workaround I have found is `git ls-tree`, which does *not* print the argument's own hash, but prints a list of its children and their hashes. You can invoke it on the commit of the tree-ish you're looking for, and then grep and slice the output to get the tree hash of path X in that commit.

```
## -r means 'recurse'
## -d means 'show trees (folders), don't show files'
$ git ls-tree -rd v2.12 | awk '/\tanimals\/ant/ {print $3}'
8ae98d5905e175575c2f56288d79c719c414d834
```

So. Is there a Git command that, given a tree-ish such as `mycommit:my/path`, will print the corresponding tree hash?

Comment: `git rev-parse v2.12:animals/ant`. (Add `^{tree}` to have rev-parse assert for you that this is a tree hash and not a blob hash, if you wish.)

Comment: Thanks, @torek, that answer works for me. Do you want to submit it as an actual answer, so that I can accept it? If you prefer, I can also submit it as an answer myself. (That way people can see the question has been answered.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `git rev-parse` program can do this easily.  One of its primary jobs is to turn any *name* into a Git *object ID* in accordance with the rules set out in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions):

```
git rev-parse v2.12:animals/ant
```

gets you the desired hash ID here.

As the documentation says, if you want to verify that the resulting object is specifically a *tree* object (and not one of the other kinds of objects), you can add a suffix:

```
git rev-parse v2.12:animals/ant^{tree}
```

In some cases, adding a suffix tells `git rev-parse` to find that particular kind of object.  For instance, a branch name always resolve to a commit object by default, but a commit object always has an associated top-level tree, so:

```
git rev-parse master
```

generally finds a commit object,<sup>1</sup> while:

```
git rev-parse master^{tree}
```

finds the corresponding top level tree, holding the snapshot data for the commit found by the un-suffixed branch name.

---

<sup>1</sup>The cases in which this *does not* produce a commit hash ID include:

- if there is *no* name `master`, so that there is no way to resolve the name; or
- if the abbreviated name `master` resolves to a *tag name* (by rule 3, which comes before rule 4 that would resolve `master` to a branch name) and the tag name names some object that is not a commit object.

Tag names like `v1.2` tend to resolve to either tag objects or commit objects.  Hence one somewhat common idiom is:

```
git rev-parse ${name}^{commit}
```

to find the commit object, or:

```
git rev-parse ${name}^{}
```

to find the target object if one intends to allow an annotated tag name to resolve to a tree or blob hash as well.  (Empty braces like this are allowed with commit objects and have no effect.)

Be somewhat wary of using this syntax for arbitrary strings that might include, e.g., `:/bug123` as adding a suffix alters the search string.  To handle this case, consider using two `git rev-parse` steps:

```
hash=$(git rev-parse "$1") || exit
hash=$(git rev-parse $hash^{}) || exit
```

Answer (score 1):

torek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61556764/8910547) is what you seek specifically, but just in case here's an alternate that does something a little different and often very useful:

```
git log --pretty="%T" -1 v2.12 -- animals/ant
```

produces the tree hash of the last commit to change animals/ant up through v2.12.

- You can supply any *commit-ish* and any file or directory path.

  ```
  git log --pretty="%T" -1 <commit-ish> -- <path>
  ```
- Use `%t` instead of `%T` to see the abbreviated hash. Of course you can substitute or add [any other format code](https://devhints.io/git-log-format), e.g. `%H` for commit hash and `%ai` for author date.
- Remove the `-1` to see all the commits up through the given *commit-ish*, not just the last.